# On kernels in the category of sets (more specifically, kernels of maps between stalks)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, germs

There's a functor that taakes a presheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ and assigns to it the stalk at $x$, written $\mathcal F_x$. There's also a result saying that this functor is exact. In proving this, we have to deal with the kernel and the image of maps $\mathcal F_x\to\mathcal G_x$ in the category of sets. If I don't want to deal with the genral notion of kernels/images in abelian categories, is it right to think of kernels and images in the category of sets in the most natural way, namely as of the set of elements sent to zero and the set of elements that come from something, respectively?

And a related question (if what I said above makes sense), what is "zero" in $\mathcal G$? If we're dealing with with the presheaf of some functions, I suppose it is the equivalence class of the pair $(U,0)$, where $0$ is the zero function. But what is it for general presheaves?

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the result I'm referring to is probably about presheaves of abelian groups...

Comment: A functor can equivalently be said to be left exact if it commutes with finite limits, right exact if it commutes with finite colimits, and exact if it's both left and right exact. That the stalkification functor (of sheaves of sets over $X$ to some $x\in X$) is right exact follows from its definition as a left adjoint; that the same is left exact follows from that limits of sheaves compute pointwise and that filtered colimits commute with finite limits.

Comment: As for your second question, the category of sheaves of sets on a space $X$ almost never has a zero object.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant categories in your case are not abelian, so your interpretation of the meaning of exact functor is incorrect. A functor is exact if it preserves finite limits and finite colimits. The functor you are looking at has a simple description: $\mathcal F_x = \mathrm{colim} (F{\mid}_x)$, namely the colimit of the restriction of $\mathcal F$ to neighbourhoods of $x$.You should now be able to check the properties of this functor.

Comment: Yeah I realized that I should be talking about presheaves of abelian groups. And I guess in the proper setup I can use the definition of the exact functor that I wanted to use (short exact sequences are mapped to short exact sequences).

Comment: Actually Vakil states this result only for sheaves of abelian groups, but I thought I proved it for presheaves of abelian groups. Is it true for presheaves as well? If not, then my proof must be incorrect.